# python - check at the end of the loop if need to run again

Tags: python, loops

It's a really basic question but i can't think at the second. How do i set up a loop that asks each time the function inside runs whether to do it again. So it runs it then says something like;

"loop again? y/n"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
while True:
    func()
    answer = raw_input( "Loop again? " )
    if answer != 'y':
        break
```

Answer (score 6):

```
keepLooping = True
while keepLooping:
  # do stuff here

  # Prompt the user to continue
  q = raw_input("Keep looping? [yn]: ")
  if not q.startswith("y"):
    keepLooping = False
```

Comment: +1: formal exit condition without a break (Also, I removed the extra print)

Comment: Aaah, thanks S. Lott. I was racing, and missed that one -- thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

There are two usual approaches, both already mentioned, which amount to:

```
while True:
    do_stuff() # and eventually...
    break; # break out of the loop
```

or

```
x = True
while x:
    do_stuff() # and eventually...
    x = False # set x to False to break the loop
```

Both will work properly. From a "sound design" perspective it's best to use the second method because 1) `break` can have counterintuitive behavior in nested scopes in some languages; 2) the first approach is counter to the intended use of "while"; 3) your routines should always have a single point of exit

Comment: Now, if only you kept the two code bits and removed the final three paragraphs, I promise I will upvote you ;)

Comment: There, I've made it more to the point. Just out of curiosity, was there something wrong with what I said or was it just how I said it?

Answer (score 1):

```
While raw_input("loop again? y/n ") != 'n':
    do_stuff()
```