# program not giving proper output

Tags: python, loops

```py
number = int(input(" guess the number: "))

for number in range(0,20):
    if number < 13:
        print("number is smaller")
    elif number > 13:
        print("number is greater")
    else:
        print("Correct guess!!")
```

Why does not the code give me correct output as expected

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: you do not know markdown. and it is badly formatted without any description of the problem.

Comment: What proper output ? Post your code properly, expected output and your output.

Comment: i have submitted a edit please accept it

Comment: Check out this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849281/python-looping-an-input

Comment: This is super beginner Python stuff. Maybe you should first start learning about the language in some online tutorials before asking questions on Stack Overflow. I don't meant to hurt your feelings, it's just that if you don't know the basics, there's no point in coming here. With `for number in range(...)` you are overwriting the number you asked your user at the beginning. Your overwriting it 20 times.

Comment: The following is Python's documentation. Always start there, when you are having problems https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements as well as https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range

Answer (score 2):

I think you have used the variable 'number' to take input and you are using it to iterate in the for loop too. That is why it is causing error, use some other variable in the for loop.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: well you are in part right but he is trying to make a guess the number program

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `for` loop, instead use a `while` loop.

```py
number = int()

def check_num():
  try:
   number = int(input('Enter the number: '))
   while number != 13: 
    if number < 13: 
       print("number is smaller") 
    elif number > 13: 
       print("number is greater") 
    else: 
        print("Correct guess!!")
        
    number = int(input('Enter the number: '))
  except ValueError:
    print('Only type numbers!')
    check_num()
    
check_num()
```

Output:-

```
Enter the number:  avengers
Only type numbers!
Enter the number:  2
number is smaller
Enter the number:  23
number is greater
Enter the number:  13
```

Comment: Please consider upvoting and putting a tick mark!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not supposed to be using a for loop for what you want because it just changes the input number. Here is the easy fix with random numbers:

```py
import random

start_of_range = 0 # Number will be random number between these
end_of_range = 100
number_to_guess = random.randint(start_of_range, end_of_range)

while True:
    try:
        number = int(input("Guess the number: "))
    except:
        print("Enter a valid number")
        continue
    if number == number_to_guess:
        print("Correct Guess")
        break
    elif number < number_to_guess:
        print("Number is less")
    else:
        print("Number is more")
```