# Keep asking for input until input is correct python. For a lotto program that needs 6 inputs between 1 and 59

Tags: python

This is what I need: Write a function that asks the user for 6 numbers between 1 and 59 and returns a list with the numbers entered by the user. If the user enters a wrong number or a repeated number an error message appears and the user is asked again for another number until 6 valid numbers are inputted.

And this is what ive done so far:

```
    lotto1 =int(input("Enter a lotto1 number 1 to 59: "))
if lotto1 < 1:
  print("Wrong number, number between 1 and 59 please")
elif lotto1 > 59:
  print("Wrong number, number between 1 and 59 please")

lotto2 =int(input("Enter a lotto2 number 1 to 59: "))
if lotto2 < 1:
  print("Wrong number, number between 1 and 59 please")
elif lotto2 > 59:
  print("Wrong number, number between 1 and 59 please")
elif lotto2 == lotto1:
  print("Repeated number, enter another number please")

lotto3 =int(input("Enter a lotto3 number 1 to 59: "))
if lotto3 < 1:
  print("Wrong number, number between 1 and 59 please")
elif lotto3 > 59:
  print("Wrong number, number between 1 and 59 please")
elif lotto3 == lotto2:
  print("Repeated number, enter another number please")
elif lotto3 == lotto1:
  print("Repeated number, enter another number please")

lotto4 =int(input("Enter a lotto4 number 1 to 59: "))
if lotto4 < 1:
  print("Wrong number, number between 1 and 59 please")
elif lotto4 > 59:
  print("Wrong number, number between 1 and 59 please")
elif lotto4 == lotto1:
  print("Repeated number, enter another number please")
elif lotto3 == lotto2:
  print("Repeated number, enter another number please")
elif lotto4 == lotto3:
  print("Repeated number, enter another number please")

lotto5 =int(input("Enter a lotto5 number 1 to 59: "))
if lotto5 < 1:
  print("Wrong number, number between 1 and 59 please")
elif lotto5 > 59:
  print("Wrong number, number between 1 and 59 please")
elif lotto5 == lotto1:
  print("Repeated number, enter another number please")
elif lotto5 == lotto2:
  print("Repeated number, enter another number please")
elif lotto5 == lotto3:
  print("Repeated number, enter another number please")
elif lotto5 == lotto4:
  print("Repeated number, enter another number please")

lotto6 =int(input("Enter a lotto number 1 to 59: "))
if lotto6 < 1:
  print("Wrong number, number between 1 and 59 please")
elif lotto6 > 59:
  print("Wrong number, number between 1 and 59 please")
elif lotto6 == lotto1:
  print("Repeated number, enter another number please")
elif lotto6 == lotto2:
  print("Repeated number, enter another number please")
elif lotto6 == lotto3:
  print("Repeated number, enter another number please")
elif lotto6 == lotto4:
  print("Repeated number, enter another number please")
elif lotto6 == lotto5:
  print("Repeated number, enter another number please")
```

The issue is that when the input is wrong, the code still moves to the next lotto number.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849281/python-looping-an-input. Add valid input inside the while loop condition and break when you have six inputs.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is loops, loop a single input until it's correct and loop this for every number, this way you don't need to write the whole thing out every time.
Consider this code:

```py
lotto_numbers = []
for i in range(1,7):
    input_correct = False
    while not input_correct:
        number = input(f"Enter a lotto{i} number 1 to 59: ")
        if not number.isnumeric():
            print("Not a number, enter a number please")
            continue
        else:
            number = int(number)
            if not 1 <= number <= 59:
                print("Wrong number, number between 1 and 59 please")
                continue
            elif number in lotto_numbers:
                print("Repeated number, enter another number please")
            else:
                lotto_numbers.append(number)
                input_correct = True
```

Feel free to ask if you don't understand all of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while True` loop

This code should do the trick:

```py
l = []
while True:
    n = int(input("Enter a lotto1 number 1 to 59: "))
    if n >= 1 and n <= 59 and n not in l:
        l.append(n)
        if len(l) == 6:
            break
    elif n < 1 or n > 59:
        print("Wrong number, number between 1 and 59 please")
    elif n in l:
        print("Repeated number, enter another number please")
```

`l` is the list that stores the lottos.

Comment: `elif n <= 1 and n >= 59:` - that should be 'or' instead of 'and'

Comment: Oops ok I'll change that now