# Trying to write a lottery program that generates 6 numbers, asks the user for 6 numbers, then compares the numbers and outputs a certain prize

Tags: python

I've written a function for generating 6 numbers:

```
import random

def createList():
  print (random.sample(range(1,59), 6))

createList()
```

And ive written a function that asks for 6 numbers and returns the numbers:

```
Lottery = []
for i in range(1,7):
    input_correct = False
    while not input_correct:
        number = input(f"Please input pick number {i} between 1 to 59: ")
        if not number.isnumeric():
            print("Please enter an Integer")
            continue
        else:
            number = int(number)
            if not 1 <= number <= 59:
                print("Please enter a number between 1 and 59.")
                continue
            elif number in Lottery:
                print("Sorry you have chosen this number already, please try again.")
            else:
                Lottery.append(number)
                input_correct = True

print (Lottery)
```

The program should then output from this:

6 numbers =JackPot

5 numbers = £1000

4 numbers = £100

3 numbers = £25

Less than 3 numbers =Sorry try again next week

Comment: `createList` should return the list, not print it. Then you can compare the numbers entired by the user with the list.

Comment: Use sets instead of lists. Then you can use intersection to find out how many numbers match.

Comment: Why not continue the discussion on the question this code is copied from? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72890519/keep-asking-for-input-until-input-is-correct-python-for-a-lotto-program-that-ne/ The answerer did say "Feel free to ask if you don't understand the code."